# text-wrap in navbar dropdown doesnt work through css, it works through html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown in BS4 navbar. The content goes out of the container on mobile device. I want to wrap the text through css.

Following code works:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" >
    {% for department in object.departments.all %}
        <a class="dropdown-item text-wrap" href="">
            {{ department.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 30vw;
}
```

But following code doesnt work:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" >
    {% for department in object.departments.all %}
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">
            {{ department.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 30vw;
}
.dropdown-item{
  text-wrap:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to use the [`white-space`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) property or possibly to use [`word-wrap`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) or [`text-overflow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).

I've not heard of the `text-wrap` property in css.

Comment: @Aseem glad to hear it worked out, don't forget to mark the question as resolved if it provided a solution by clicking the check mark next to the answer